# rails - display partial in another controllers view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I'm not sure why i can't get my index action to pass to my view.  Basically i have a controller called "jobs" with a partial called "recent jobs" and i want to display that "recent jobs" partial in another contollers view called "static_pages".

I thought that all i would have to do is call the below in my static_pages/home.html.erb:

```
    <%= render partial: "jobs/recent_jobs" %>
```

but here's the error i get.  apparently @jobs is nil.

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass):
2: <div class="homepage_recent_jobs">
3:   <div class="container">
4:       
5:     <% @jobs.each do |job| %>
6:       <% job.title %>
7:     <% end %>
8:
```

here's my partial in the jobs controller

```
    <div class="homepage_recent_jobs">
      <div class="container">

        <% @jobs.each do |job| %>
          <% job.title %>
        <% end %>
     </div>
   </div>
```

jobs index action

```
def index

  set_link_order_and_counters      

  @jobs = Job.all

  # calls scopes
  if params[:experience].present? 
    @jobs = @jobs.by_experience(params[:experience])
  end   

  if params[:num_days_past].present? 
    @jobs = @jobs.by_num_days_past(params[:num_days_past].to_i)
  end      


  @jobs = @jobs.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 5)
end
```

Comment: When I started testing I realized that I didn't need to pass the local variables with the partial or modify the each block like you first mentioned.  All that was needed was just to add @jobs = Job.all  to the static_pages home controller.  You mentioned this further down in the comments so I up voted that answer.  If you want to make your comment a separate answer that i can mark correct I'm more than happy to make that the accepted answer.  i just didn't want someone is the future who was having the same issue to be confused.  Thank you again for your help.

Comment: You're right. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you're working with `@jobs`, and rendering `static_pages#home` you need to define it first, you've defined it only in `jobs#index`, and that's why when the view is rendered the value is `nil`.

Adding `@jobs` in the proper controller should work:

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
    @jobs = Job.all
  end
end
```

And note with `<%= render 'jobs/recent_jobs' %>` Rails infers is a partial file, no need to use the `partial` option. Also to print the job's title you would need to use `<%= %>`.

Comment: I think what is still missing is that you have to fetch the jobs in the controller that renders the partial and assign them to @jobs

Comment: I think yes, I see `@jobs = Job.all` but in the `jobs#index`, and he's rendering the partial in `static_pages#home`, still unclear, thanks for pointing out that.

Comment: yes I'm trying to render the "recent_jobs" partial in static_pages#home.  I tried the above suggestion from @SebastianPalma but i still receive the same error

Comment: Just assign @jobs = Job.all in static_pages#home and you should be good to go

Comment: You need to assigns in `static_pages#home` the `@jobs` variable, otherwise it won't be available nor for your view, nor for your partial.